# ui-grid infinite scrolling feature with chunk support

Tags: angularjs, ng-grid, angular-ui-grid

I would like to know whether the ui-grid/nggrid infinite scrolling feature supports loading of data from the server in chunks

Now that all the demos that i have seen pulls the data from server all at once which would not be possible in my case.

So if I set the page size as 30 and once it reaches the bottom then the server call is made to fetch another 30 records and so on. Is this feature builtin using the existing methods or we need to make it work using some other custom logic ?

please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, ng-grid is what is being re written as ui-grid.

The feature you are looking for is achievable with proper server implementation.

ui-grid does not pull all the data from the server. See this page http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/212_infinite_scroll. The example (for simplicity) has all the data pulled and on getDataDown and getDataUp shows the correct page based on the user scroll but it is not a required step.

If you have your server end point to page the table content properly, you can invoke the server calls inside getDataDown() and getDataUp() based on the current page you are viewing. But as mentioned in the example, you will have to track the page numbers to properly retrieve the correct page data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement OnScrollListener interface in your adapter. When your grid reaches at the end you can make next call to web service.

[OnScrollListener link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.OnScrollListener.html)

Comment: This has nothing to do with Angular UI-GRID..The link you are referring to is for android native app development.